# DOMNodeInserted equivalent in IE?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom, mutation-events

Other than using a timer to count the number of elements over time and looking for changes, I can't think of a better way to simulate this event.

Is there some sort of proprietary IE version of DOMNodeInserted? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there isn't. The nearest is the `propertychange` event, which fires in response to a change in an attribute or CSS property of an element. It fires in response to changing the `innerHTML` property of an element directly but not when the contents of the elements are altered by some other means (e.g. by using DOM methods such as `appendChild()` or by altering the `innerHTML` of a child element).

#### UPDATE 6 February 2014

As pointed out in the comments, there is a workaround. It's based on an elaborate hack and I'd recommend using mutation observers instead wherever possible. <strike>See @naugtur's answer for details</strike>. @naugtur's answer has been deleted but the solution can be found  at https://github.com/naugtur/insertionQuery

Comment: javascript:var div = document.createElement("div"); div.onpropertychange = function() { var e = window.event; alert(e.propertyName + ": " + this[e.propertyName]); }; document.body.appendChild(div); div.innerHTML = "Hello"; void(0);

Comment: @Sean: OK, I wasn't clear. What I meant was that `propertychange` does not fire for `innerHTML` when the content of an element changes by any means other than setting its `innerHTML` property directly, which makes it pretty much useless as a workaround for `DOMNodeInserted`: http://jsfiddle.net/eze5V/8/. I've updated my answer.

Comment: See my answer. It is possible to simulate this event and it has been done, although it is probably more effort than it is worth.

Comment: @Sean: I saw it. Overriding all DOM methods and properties that could change the DOM is simply not possible, so that's a non-starter as a general solution.

Comment: There is a solution for IE10+ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143929/domnodeinserted-equivalent-in-ie/21600446#21600446

Comment: @naugtur: Thanks. I did read about that a few weeks ago. The approach is clever but an obvious hack. I don't like it, but I guess it's better than nothing.

Comment: @TimDown This is more of an outside-of-the-box idea than a hack. It's based on a feature from spec that was implemented earlier, it has its pros (free CSS selectors) and cons (delay in firing the event up to 40ms) but it's much less of a hack than JSONP, and look at the adoption ;)

Comment: @naugtur: I don't like JSONP either :)

Comment: @naugtur, where did this infamous "actual, if hacky but not actually hacky solution" go?

Comment: @Brad: naugtur's answer has been deleted but I can still see it. The solution can be found at https://github.com/naugtur/insertionQuery.

Comment: I had multiple answers pointing to insertionQuery, but they got deleted. I wanted to bring them back, but couldn't get moderator support for it. I gave up. Only one of them got brought back. But the lib is working and stable.

Answer (score 6):

You can over-ride all the DOM-manipulation methods - appendChild, insertBefore, replaceChild, insertAdjacentHTML, etc - and monitor innerHTML with onpropertychange.

You might be able to come up with a solution that satisfies your requirements.

BTW, it seems that DOMNodeInserted, etc will be deprecated by browsers in the future.
See http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#events-mutationevents

Comment: just curious, where did you see the deprecation part about DOMNodeInserted?

Comment: @Anurag Note: The MutationEvent interface was introduced in DOM Level 2 Events, but has not yet been completely and interoperably implemented across user agents. In addition, there have been critiques that the interface, as designed, introduces a performance and implementation challenge. A new specification is under development with the aim of addressing the use cases that mutation events solves, but in more performant manner. Thus, this specification describes mutation events for completeness, but deprecates the use of both the MutationEvent interface and the MutationNameEvent interface.

Comment: Any idea what that new specification might be, or where it's implemented?

Comment: "monitor innerHTML with onpropetrychange." - I don't understand. onproperychange will not fire if innerHTML is changed (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536956(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @ripper234: From the page you referenced: "Changing the innerText or innerHTML of *child* elements will not cause the onpropertychange event to fire for the *parent* element. "

Answer (score 3):

onreadystatechange will work in IE. A DHTML behavior must be attached to the element via htc, but the htc file does not have to exist:

```
if (!!document.addEventListener)
  {
  $(domnode).get(0).addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", fixtext, false);
  }
else
  {
  $(domnode).get(0).addBehavior("foo.htc");
  $(domnode).get(0).attachEvent("onreadystatechange", fixtext);
  }
```

[onreadystatechange event reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536957%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

A dirty workaround is to intercept the prototype methods of type Element as follows:

```
window.attachEvent('onload', function() {
    invokeNodeInserted(document);
    (function(replace) {
        Element.prototype.appendChild = function(newElement, element) {
            invokeNodeInserted(newElement);
            return replace.apply(this, [newElement, element]);
        };
    })(Element.prototype.appendChild);
    (function(replace) {
        Element.prototype.insertBefore = function(newElement, element) {
            invokeNodeInserted(newElement);
            return replace.apply(this, [newElement, element]);
        };
    })(Element.prototype.insertBefore);
    (function(replace) {
        Element.prototype.replaceChild = function(newElement, element) {
            invokeNodeInserted(newElement);
            return replace.apply(this, [newElement, element]);
        };
    })(Element.prototype.replaceChild);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using onreadystatechange as suggested by Paul Sweatte does not really work. The readystatechange event is only triggered while loading foo.htc. It has nothing to do with changing the DOM node.

I've set up a little fiddle to demonstrate it. Have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/Kermit_the_frog/FGTDv/ or http://jsfiddle.net/Kermit_the_frog/FGTDv/embedded/result/.

HTML:

```
<input type="button" id="fooBtn" value="add" />
<div id="fooDiv"></div>
```

JS/Jquery:

```
function bar(e) {
    var state = $('#fooDiv').get(0).readyState;
    alert (state);
}

$("#fooBtn").on("click", function(){
    $('#fooDiv').get(0).addBehavior("foo.htc");
    $('#fooDiv').get(0).attachEvent("onreadystatechange", bar);
});
```

As you can see: even though there is no DOM manipulation going on there is a readystatechange event.

Answer (score -2):

Seems, DHTML Behaviors can be used in IE to emulative `DOMNodeInserted`.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: You didn't said much. If you do have a solution, please provide it here. There is no place here for false statements.