# New Elements Added to DOM, should report a function. (using Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose I am having a DOM structure like this,

```
<body>
    <!-- Dom elements -->

    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>

    <!--More Dom elements -->
</body>
```

You can see there are three elements with `class= red`. Now suppose of because some user activity two more elements are added to DOM like below.

```
<body>
    <!-- Dom elements -->

    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>

    <div class="red"></div> <!--New element added because of some user activity -->
    <div class="red"></div> <!--New element added because of some user activity -->

    <!--More Dom elements -->
</body>
```

Now i want some mechanism that whenever news elements get added to DOM they report to a function.

Below is a hypothetical function iam looking for

```
jQuery('.red').onAddedToDom_AfterDomReady(function(){
               //do something to all added elemnents
               //like bind some events to them etc
});
```

Is there any existing feature in jQuery that iam missing or any plugin that may help!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a jQuery DOM change listener?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844565/is-there-a-jquery-dom-change-listener)

Comment: just checked this answer, its not what iam looking for!!

Comment: Sounds like the code should trigger an event when new elements are added. Just listen for the event and you know what action to take when fires.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would rely on the [`DOMNodeInserted`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-DOMNodeInserted) event which is not supported in IE.

[See related question for IE support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143929/domnodeinserted-equivalent-in-ie)

Basically you have to periodically poll the DOM for any new elements and that's rather expensive.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.live()` method of jQuery. It works on limited events of future matching elements. API [link](http://api.jquery.com/live/).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just adding a `<div>` element, if you have a widget and if you insert them, then u can have a 'onattach' handler on that widget

Creating a jquery widget - http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/tips-for-developing-jquery-ui-widgets/ . It shows that there is a _create method that can be overridden to do what you want when the widget is being created. So you can replace the div class red tags with a widget and have a _create method

Comment: unable to understand what you are saying!!