# Backbone render return this

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm trying to figure out some of the 'patterns' to set up a Backbone-project. In the examples below, in the 'render'-function, the author returns an instance of 'this'.

Why is this? Is it specific for the example, or something common for Backbone? I don't see why one should return 'this' in the 'render'-function.

**The examples**

http://backbonefu.com/2011/08/filtering-a-collection-in-backbone-js/

[Calling a jQuery plugin in a Backbone render method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7107904/calling-a-jquery-plugin-in-a-backbone-render-method)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is just a common practice so you can call `render()` and to chain another method call.

It is a common pattern that the *Views* don't insert its HTML content in the page, and this job is done by the instance that instantiate the *View* in a first place.

Then what you have to write in the code that instantiate the View is something like this:

```
var myView = new MyView({ model: myModel });
myView.render();
$(myDOMElement).html( myView.el );
```

But if `render()` returns the View itself you can write the above code like this:

```
var myView = new MyView({ model: myModel });
$(myDOMElement).html( myView.render().el );
```

Answer (score 8):

The meaning of returning `this`, is for providing ***chaining possibilities***.

For example, lets assume:

```
 var obj = {
      prop1 : 0,
      method1 : function(){
      },
      method2 : function(){
      }
 };
 //Then you could do something like:
 obj.method1();
 obj.method2();
 obj.prop1 = 1;
```

All actions on `obj` you need to do separately.

Now consider:

```
 var obj = {
      prop1 : 0,
      method1 : function(){
          return this;
      },
      method2 : function(){
          return this;
      }
 };
 //Now you could do these
 obj.method1().prop1 = 1;
 obj.method1().method2().method1();
```

Comment: Thank's a lot! I checked fguillen's answer because it's specific for Backbone.js