# Rewriting links with javascript on a dynamic page

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm writing a script that should rewrite all links on a page from http:// to https:// *- it must be done client-side, it's run in a page I don't control.*

Execution environment: recent Chrome only, as this is a Chrome extension's injected script, so no cross-browser worries. Injection happens at `document_start` (i.e. before DOM starts loading).

My first try was to watch for `DOMContentLoaded` and then iterate over document.links:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", rewriteHTTPS, false);

function rewriteHTTPS() {
    var links = document.links;
    for(var i in links){
        links[i].href = links[i].href.replace(/http:/, "https:");
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I realized that the page is dynamic, so more links are added after this event is fired.

So, the question is: **What's the best way to capture all new and modified links in a page with dynamic DOM?**

Comment: Is there a *really* good reason as to why this isn't being done on the server side? What if your user just turns off Javascript?

Comment: I'm writing a browser extension to interact with a foreign site. Obviously, if my users use it, they have javascript enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to look into listening for the [DOMNodeInserted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143929/domnodeinserted-equivalent-in-ie) event, even thought its support in IE seems to be spotty. The other answers to that question may also be helpful.

Comment: IE is not an issue; it's a Chrome-only question and it states so. As for DOMNodeInserted: it's not triggered for ALL new DOM nodes, it seems like it fires once for each subtree insertion. Looks like I have to iterate over each such subtree..

Comment: Yes, iterating over `event.target.getElementsByTagName('a')` for `DOMNodeInserted` did the trick for me. Thanks.