# DOM Mutation event in JQuery or vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, mutation-events

Are there any DOM mutation events in JQuery or in vanilla Javascript that fire cross browser?

To clarify, say I have a script on my page which inserts a div into the body. I don't have access to the script and I don't know when the div has been inserted. I was wondering if there's a DOM mutation event that I can add a listener for, to know when an element has been inserted. I know I can use a timer to periodically check for the insertion but, I don't really like the overhead that this would impose.

Comment: Could you be a little more specific please?

Comment: I thought all the jQuery events fired cross-browser...

Comment: Support for "mutation events" is lacking in older versions of IE.  http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Events-20001113/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-mutationevents

Comment: I'm not sure that I believe that this is 'not a real question.' And, I believe, that without explanation I'll vote to re-open if closed. I'm interested in the answers here.

Comment: @DavidThomas Because people don't understand the question they are voting to close it.  It's definitely a good question.

Comment: Very interesting question. It doesn't sound like there's an existing plugin for this — would the IE callback just be to find a particular aspect of the DOM and constantly poll it to detect changes? Sounds gruesome, but it's the first thing I thought of.

Comment: Relevant: http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-webapps/2011AprJun/1318.html

Comment: Also this: http://annevankesteren.nl/2011/06/mutation

Comment: I think this has already been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143929/domnodeinserted-equivalent-in-ie

Comment: I was hoping for a better answer than no :-P

Comment: Such question calls a why. It makes me suspect that there is an ajax call and some display being done. In such case there is other solutions to that kind of issue.

Otherwise, if you know what you are doing and why, I suggest as a poor's man solution to check periodically the length of the body node.

Comment: Well, the whole problem is that i don't have control over the script injecting the data into the body. If i did, the obvious soulution would have been to add a callback.

Answer (score 24):

This is certainly a hack, but why not patch the underlying DOM methods used to insert the nodes?  There are a couple ways to do this:

**A**. You know what **specific** element will be appended to:

```
var c = document.getElementById('#container');
c.__appendChild = c.appendChild;
c.appendChild = function(){
     alert('new item added');
     c.__appendChild.apply(c, arguments); 
}
```

[fiddle demo for **A**](http://jsfiddle.net/6hZUJ/)

**B**. You know what **type** of element will be appended to:

```
HTMLDivElement.prototype.__appendChild = HTMLDivElement.prototype.appendChild;
HTMLDivElement.prototype.appendChild = function(){
    alert('new item added');
    HTMLDivElement.prototype.__appendChild(this,arguments); 
}
```

[fiddle demo for **B**](http://jsfiddle.net/PdBcg/)

(Note that solution **B** is not supported by `IE < 8` or any other browser which does not support DOM prototypes.)

This same technique could just as easily be used on all the underlying DOM mutation functions such as `insertBefore`, `replaceChild` or `removeChild`.

That's the general idea, these demos could be adapted for pretty much any other use case -- say you want to cast a wide net and catch *all* additions regardless of type **AND** make sure it works across <s>all browsers</s> everything but `IE < 8`?  (see example C below)

---

**UPDATE**

**C.** Recursively walk the DOM, swap out the function on every element to trigger a callback, and then apply the same patch to any children being appended.

```
var DOMwatcher = function(root, callback){
  var __appendChild = document.body.appendChild;

  var patch = function(node){
    if(typeof node.appendChild !== 'undefined' && node.nodeName !== '#text'){
      node.appendChild = function(incomingNode){
        callback(node, incomingNode);
        patch(incomingNode);
        walk(incomingNode);
        __appendChild.call(node, incomingNode);
      };
    }
    walk(node);  
  };

  var walk = function(node){
    var i = node.childNodes.length;
    while(i--){
      patch(node.childNodes[i]);
    }
  };

  patch(root);

};

DOMwatcher(document.body, function(targetElement, newElement){ 
   alert('append detected');    
});

$('#container ul li').first().append('<div><p>hi</p></div>');
$('#container ul li div p').append('<a href="#foo">bar</a>');
```

[fiddle demo for **C**](http://jsfiddle.net/gLCXF/)

**UPDATE 2**

As [Tim Down](https://stackoverflow.com/users/96100/tim-down) commented, the above solution also won't work in `IE < 8` because `appendChild` is not a `Function` and does not support `call` or `apply`.  I suppose you could always fall back to the clunky but trusty `setInterval` method if `typeof document.body.appendChild !== 'function'`.

Comment: This won't work in IE < 9 and is generally dodgy since host methods such as `appendChild()` are not required to be `Function` objects (and indeed aren't in IE < 9).

Comment: @TimDown Shoot! You're right, in browsers where `appendChild` is not a `Function` this solution will fail because it doesn't respond to `call` or `apply`.  Good catch, I've updated the answer to reflect this.  However, you'll find that the code above *does* work in IE 8.

Comment: Ah, OK. I was unsure about IE 8, I confess.

Comment: If you are looking for an alternative to this method, here is http://www.jqui.net/jquery-projects/jquery-mutate-official/ which can also allow you to add events yourself and keep a watch for almost any change, class name change, height change, width change.

Comment: Fascinating, and terrifying. +1!

Answer (score 8):

There are some **deprecated** DOM mutation events, such as `DOMNodeInserted` and `DOMNodeInsertedIntoDocument` that still work for me in Chrome 14 and IE9.

See an example at http://jsfiddle.net/Kai/WTJq6/

See them all on the W3C draft at http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/

Comment: IE 9 is the first version of IE that had DOM mutation events, so this won't work in IE < 9. While these events are deprecated, the spec for their replacement is not yet complete so they won't be going away for a while yet.

Comment: Great to know about IE, since I don't use it much. Btw, OT: I discovered your Rangy lib yesterday -- its awesome, ty. :)

Answer (score 4):

JCADE (JQuery Create and Destroy Events) will do this.  It uses **behaviors** for IE and **DOM mutation events** for other browsers.  It does not use timing events and does not wrap JQuery methods like livequery.

https://github.com/snesin/jcade

```
    $( document ).create( "a", function( event ) {
      alert( event.target );
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

Not without a plugin, I believe, but I wouldn't be surprised if I'm wrong.

My research has found a a few to choose from.

Here's one: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/mutation-events

Here's another: https://www.adaptavist.com/display/jQuery/Mutation+Events

Comment: This looked promising until i looked at the script code and realized they are not using jQuery to insert the div into the DOM.

Comment: Hmm, shucks.  I'll admit to not having attempted this, so I can't really speak to how they work.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for an alternative to this method, here is http://www.jqui.net/jquery-projects/jquery-mutate-official/ which can also allow you to add events yourself and keep a watch for almost any change, class name change, height change, width change.

Answer (score 0):

The [livequery](https://github.com/brandonaaron/livequery) plugin can be used for this. In version 1.x a timer was used to periodically check for any changes. However, the newer version 2.x branch seems to be working without periodical timeout (untested).