# Timer to check frequently, after change value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, settimeout, setinterval

I want any time my submit value changed to `Thanks` do something for me, my submit id is `#pollsubmit`

So i tried to solve the problem with `setTimeout( function()`

But i think this is not a good solution and there may be a better solution to this problem

```
$("#pollsubmit").on("click", function() {
  setTimeout( function() { 
    if($("#pollsubmit").val() == 'Thanks'){
      // Do Something
    }else{
        setTimeout( function() { 
           if($("#pollsubmit").val() == 'Thanks'){
            // Do Something
            }else{
              setTimeout( function() { 
                 if($("#pollsubmit").val() == 'Thanks'){
                   // Do Something
                 }else{
                 }
              },1500);
            }
        },1500);
       }
  },1500);
});
```

The problem is, i do not know how many seconds it takes to change the `value` of a **submit** to `Thanks`

---

before ask this question i read [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6458840/detecting-input-change-in-jquery) but my question is different, because the value of my button after clicking first changes to `Loading` and then to `Thanks`, in fact i need a timer to check frequently, after change value,

ex:

Button value is `Submit` after Click

First: Value changed to `Loading`

Second: Value changed to `Thanks`

---

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detecting input change in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6458840/detecting-input-change-in-jquery)

Comment: Who is "#pollsubmit"?

Comment: @alam7o This question seems to be an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), and while it could be "solved" with an interval, there is still information missing which could potentially make the answer considerably simpler, like what is causing the input's value to change in the first place.

Comment: Better would be to add a change event listener to the **button** and trigger a change event whenever you are changing the value of the **button**. Refer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28360149/how-to-detect-button-value-change-in-jquery

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy in fact before ask this question check  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6458840/detecting-input-change-in-jquery) topic, but not helping me

Comment: @ArthurRubens `#pollsubmit` is id of submit button for my form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could activate a timer and check frequently, after the change cancel it

```
 $("#pollsubmit").on("click", function() {
      const id = setInterval(() => {
        if ($("#pollsubmit").val() == 'Thanks') {
          clearInterval(id)
          //Do Something
        }
      }, 100);
    });
```

Comment: yup and we can use recursive function as well

Comment: @YerrapotuManojKiran Which is better and more optimal?