# jQuery: Observe an enumerable/selector

Tags: jquery

Using `$("#myTable tr").live("click", someCallback);` (although now deprecated) it is fairly simple to subscribe to the click event for newly added table rows.

I would be interested in a way which doesn't only support events but any jQuery commands, something like:

```
$("myTable tr").live().attr("hello", "world");
```

which would add the hello="world" attribute to any newly added table rows. Is there any such thing in jQuery?

**Update: Please note**. I want to *subscribe* to the event of an element being added. I do *not* control the code which adds it. Take dataTables as a example: The dataTables plug-in creates the table rows.

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7692730/dom-mutation-event-in-jquery-or-vanilla-javscript/7749629#7749629

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say there are two reasons why this doesn't really exist.

1. DOM modification events are not widely supported.  You could listen for `DOMSubtreeModified` in Chrome and FF, but not in IE and Opera.
2. Checking every DOM event against a selector would be very costly. `.live/.delegate` is already pretty inefficient of a strategy.

To help picture 2, imagine that 1 isn't a problem and we can capture any time an element is added to the DOM.  When this happens, we need to evaluate the new element and its children against `"#myTable tr"`.  This will significantly increase the amount of non-native code executing with **every** DOM change in scope, really slowing things down.

The best strategy is to add your desired jQuery changes to the code that would be inserting the `<tr>`

**UPDATE** If you have no choice *and* only have to support Chrome and FF, there is one solution I can think of.  Obviously, it will not be fast and you can improve your performance through specificity:

```
$.fn.elementInserted = function(pattern, fn) {
    return this.bind('DOMNodeInserted', function(event) {
            if (event.target.nodeType != 1) return;
            $(event.target).filter(pattern).each(fn);
    });
};

/* SLOW */ $(document).elementInserted('#myTable tr', function(){$(this).attr('hello', 'world');});
/* FASTER */ $('#myTable').elementInserted('tr', function(){$(this).attr('hello', 'world');});
```

See an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/vCZHQ/

You could theoretically check if the table has changed in IE by doing a timeout:

```
var oldEls = $('#myTable tr');
setInterval(function() {
    var newEls = $('#myTable tr');
    if(oldEls.length < newEls.length) {
        /* Do code here to figure out who is new and apply changes. */
    }
    oldEls = newEls;
}, 50);
```

That said, this will have a slight delay and really drain a laptop's battery.

Comment: Thanks. I understand your points. Unfortunately the code that adds the row is not by me. I have updated my question accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate edit. It is a pity that IE does not support this event...

Answer (score 2):

I think you should add the code that adds the hello attribute to the row in a callback function or something on the statement that actually adds the row to the table.

Comment: I've updated my question. Unfortunately the code that adds the row is not by me.