# How can I create a custom event using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I want to create an event when the content of a div changes, the event is called..

```
change = function(oldval,newval){
    if (oldval != newval){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I want this function to be called everytime the content of a div changes ..Any idea how i can achieve this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DOM Mutation event in JQuery or vanilla Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7692730/dom-mutation-event-in-jquery-or-vanilla-javascript). Some of the answers there link to jQuery plugins that might solve your problem. Handling DOM mutation events is often trickier than it looks, though.

Answer (score 1):

> I want this function to be called everytime the content of an element changes

If the content of an element equals to the value of form inputs:

One line code:

```
$(':input', $('#divId')).change(function(){alert('changed');});
```

Or the delegate option for dynamic added elements (still one line... **(;** ):

```
$('#divId').on('change', ':input', function(){ alert('changed');});
```

**docs:**

- [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)
- [`:input` selector](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/)

Comment: Why does this get upvoted? It won't raise the event when the content of the `<div>` changes, but when the value of a form control inside of it changes, which is not the same thing at all. And the last sentence is not even complete...

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi. I'm sure this is what the qustion owner meant. **"content of an element changes"**

Comment: Indeed, `content of a div changes`, not `value of form controls inside a div changes`. I'm afraid the questioner is looking for the former (mutation events), not the latter...

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi. We shall wait for the question owner response... Anyway it's a good answer, the question isn't clear enough.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi.  "content of an element changes" not "content of a div changes"!

Comment: Both sentences are actually present in the question... not that it makes a difference anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If you arent planning on supporting IE you can use DOMNodeInserted and DOMNodeRemoved to check if elements are added or removed from your div.

```
$('#yourDiv').bind('DOMNodeInserted DOMNodeRemoved', function(event, oldvalue, newvalue) {
   if (oldval != newval){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});
```

for IE support you can use

```
$(function() {
  var $div = $("#yourDiv");
  var content = $div.html();
  var look = setInterval(function() {
    var newcontent = $div.html();
    if (html != newcontent ) {
      change(content, newcontent); 
      content = newcontent;
    }
  },100);

  function change(oldval, newval() {
     if (oldval != newval){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: where do the `oldvalue, newvalue` values come from ?!