# Reapply JS to dynamic generated content

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic-rebinding

What is the best way to reapply JS to dynamic generated content? I said "reapply JS" and not "rebind events" because a meant "reapply JS that bind events and also changes the dom", what I have done so far is something like this:

```
main.js:
function repplyDynamic(){
    $('.dynamic:not(.js-initialized)').each(function(){
        $(this).addClass('js-initialized').append('<div class="chaging_dom"></div>').click(function(){
            alert("Ae!");
        });
    });
}


other_code.js
$('body').append('<div id="dynamic">content</div>'); // could be a ajax call
reapplyDynamic();
```

But I think this is very messy. Do you guys have a better approach?

Comment: Just curiosity (I'm also and have seen your "Ae!")

Comment: kkk... I guess this isn't very common in here, right? xD

Answer (score 1):

Personally I have a function called `dommods()` that does all the modification I need (tooltips, forms, auto-sizing textareas, etc.) and call it after every nontrivial change to the DOM.

In other words, exactly what you're doing but with a different function name. Nothing wrong with it.

Comment: Yes, but I wanted something more organized, that I don't need to specify if an element was already "initialize" with a class/data. Maybe a plugin?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery's $().on method](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to attach event handlers to present or future HTML elements.

Comment: This solves it if I only needed to reattach events. But I also need to change the DOM.

Comment: Check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7692730/dom-mutation-event-in-jquery-or-vanilla-javascript - it shows several methods to monitor DOM changes with jQuery

Answer (score 0):

```
//main.js
function applyDynamicStuff(content){
    return content                                  //return content
        .append('<div class="chaging_dom"></div>')  //with appended element
        .click(function(){                          //with click hander
            alert("Ae!");
        });
}

//other_code.js 
var dynamicItem = $('<div>content</div>')           //the new content
applyDynamicStuff(dynamicItem).appendTo('body');    //apply Dynamic stuff and append to body
```