# jquery .live() and .append()

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, jquery-append

So I'm currently using .append() to add a feature to all of the posts on a webpage, but when additional posts are loaded on the page, the appended features aren't included in the new content — I'm trying to come up with a way to make sure all of the new content has the appended feature too.

```
$(this).append('<div id="new_feature></div>');
```

Something like this?

```
$(this).live().append('<div id="new_feature></div>');
```

Maybe there's a way to make it constantly appending in a loop perhaps?

Comment: Are you aware that you have spelled append wrong in your code?

Comment: This is not how `.live` works ([check the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/live/)). Whenever you load new posts you have to add the features to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`jQuery` documentation:

> Use of the .live() method is no longer recommended since later versions of jQuery offer better methods that do not have its drawbacks.

You can use `setTimeout()` function that can check for new `<div>`s every n milliseconds.

```
$(function(){
    setInterval("Check4NewDivs();",1000);
});
```

So say `this` is a div with `class="comment newdiv"`, so when it appears on the page for the first time, it has the class `newdiv` that will let the function know it was just dynamically created.

```
function Check4NewDivs(){
    $(".comment .newdiv").each(function(){
        $(this).append('<div class="new_feature"></div>').removeClass("newdiv");
    });
}
```

Comment: I tried implementing this — what's happening now is that I'm getting multiple copies of the new feature being rapidly adding over and over again to each post.

Comment: You must add something that lets JS know it's a newly formed `<div>`. This is why I said if you have it so when a new `<div>` appears, it has the class `newdiv`, this will only effect the dynamically created `<div>`s. Otherwise if you just leave it as `$(".comment")`, yes it will keep adding the 'new_feature' div.

Comment: Also `<div id="new_feature>` should be `<div class="new_feature">`. All `id` attributes should be unique.

Answer (score 3):

There is DOMNodeInserted  event:

```
$('button').click(function() {
  $('#appendme').append($('<div class="inner">').text(Math.random()));

})

$('#appendme').on('DOMNodeInserted','.inner',function() {
 console.log(this); 
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/JcBvc/)

update: this seems not works in IE, try `propertychnage` event handler also (`$('#appendme').on('DOMNodeInserted,propertychange'`) but i not sure, have no IE to check this right now.

update2: Domnode* seems deprecated according to mdn, they tell to use [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/MutationObserver) object instead

update3: seems here is no very crossbrowser solution for MutationEvents, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7749629/815386), so my suggestion would be use code above, if event supported and fallback to `setTimeOut` or livequery option.

update4: 
If you depend only on `.append()` you can patch `jQuery.fn.append()` like this:

```
jQuery.fn.append=function() {
                return this.domManip(arguments, true, function( elem ) {
                        if ( this.nodeType === 1 || this.nodeType === 11 ) {
                                this.appendChild( elem );                             
                                $(elem).trigger('appended');
                        }
                });
        };

$('button').click(function() {
  $('#appendme').append($('<div class="inner">').text(Math.random()));

})

$('#appendme').on('appended','.inner',function() {
 console.log(this); 
});
```

[DEMO2](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/JcBvc/2/)

may be more correct is to spoof `jQuery.fn.domManip` like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/JcBvc/6/)

Comment: Deprecated, not removed; and there is no place for it to go yet as DOM4 is still a WD. The bigger issue with MutationEvents is the support, and possibly lack-thereof. I have no idea which browsers implement it and to which extent. I wouldn't be surprised if there were some shim libraries ..

Comment: @pst I add some jquery native examples,what you can say about such way ?

Answer (score 1):

It's `append` not `appened`.
`live` is a deprecated event handler. It's not used this way. use `on` instead.
http://api.jquery.com/live/

So, the following code will run when you click `selector`.

```
$(document).on('click', 'selector', function() {
    $(this).append('<div id="new_feature></div>');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no standard way to do it like that. There was a proposal of the events that would be fired whenever the DOM elements are inserted etc., but you cannot rely on that.

Instead rely on either:

- (preferably) callbacks - just invoke function ensuring existence of such appended snippets, whenever you pull something (but after you successfully pull it from server and insert into DOM, not sooner), or
- constant checks - like using in `setInterval()` or `setTimeout()`, but this would be unnecessary processing and you will never get instant append, unless you will perform processing-heavy checks all the time,

Comment: Ref: [MutationEvents from DOM2](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#events-mutationevents), deprecated by [MutationObservers in DOM4](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#mutation-observers)

Comment: So I should use setTimeout() to rapidly check for new content to append to?

Comment: @luke Only as a *last* effort (e.g. user modifications or modified by third-party code). If the DOM manipulation is controlled by you - e.g. from AJAX - then there is no need.

Answer (score 0):

use the on load function:

```
$(item).on('load',function(){
    $(this).append('<div id="new_feature"></div>');
});
```

This will add append the item as a callback once the item has been loaded. I would also choose some sort of dynamic ID creator rather than always append stuff with the same ID, but thats just me.

Comment: That works only if there is something to load, not when you append a text for example.

Comment: aren't new posts the items being loaded?

Comment: @TonyQuentano: Please read [jQuery's documentation on `load` event](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/), especially this part: "_The load event is sent to an element when it and all sub-elements have been completely loaded. This event can be sent to any element associated with a URL: images, scripts, frames, iframes, and the window object._". No, text-only posts are not something that is being _loaded_ in terms of `load` event. You load only something that has the URL (image, script, frame etc.).

Answer (score 0):

you must bind to an element that already exists on the page. i have written an example where i make appended content live.

[DEMO on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oud8Lnqt/)

HTML

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="features">
  </div>
  <br />
  <a href='#' id='clickme'>click me to add feature</a>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(function() {
  $('#clickme').on('click', function(e) {
    $('#features').append('<div class="new_feature">new feature</div>');
  });

  $('#features').on('click', '.new_feature', function() {
    alert('i am live.');
  });
});
```