# Call JS-function with DOM-elements

Tags: javascript, html

I'm requesting DOM-elements `.my-element` which come rendered from server and append 'em on my page.

Every time new element appears on the page I want to call JS-function `myFunction`.
I want to call this function "automatically" without using excess JS-code.

That's how I do it now. Every rendered element contains tag `script` with function call inside:

```
<div class="my-element">
    /*some structure*/
    <script>myFunction();</script>
</div>
```

But I wonder: is there some HTML-attribute who could do the same? Some like that:

```
<div class="my-element" javascript="myFunction();">/*some structure*/</div>
```

**UPD**
I don' want to call `myFunction` with the code which appending new items. I want to solve this task exactly using tag `script` or some magic attribute.

Comment: What does the JS do? Couldn't the same task be executed on the server-side?

Comment: @Teemu no, `myFunction` can't be executed on server

Comment: Can you hook myFunction with the code that is pulling the new elements from the server?

Comment: @Doug that's the point: I don want to :)

Comment: How is the element appended? Can't the JS be run there rather than adding lots of identical script tags to the page? Edit: Why would you not want to do it the way Doug suggests? If you give us some context we may be in a better position to help.

Comment: There's no such an attribute. Put a single script at the end of the body, collect all the elements with `my-element` class, loop the collection and call the function passing an element in the loop.

Comment: html does not run javascript (it just provides a place for it to load) -- that's why you'll have folks say that HTML isn't a programming language but more a structural language.  If you wanted to pull this off, you'd probably have to create extra javascript to listen for when an element is appended to the DOM and then (evaluate and) execute the JS included.

Comment: See the answer at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7692730/dom-mutation-event-in-jquery-or-vanilla-javascript maybe that works for you.

Comment: JS is not scoped to the HTML element it is nested in, so the markup you suggested actually makes very little sense. Why do you *not* want to invoke `myFunction()` with the call that appends new items? That is actually the correct way to do it.

Comment: After your edit it looks like you're creating the elements dynamically using JS. The creation function is definitely a correct place to execute some code related to the added elements. Or you can use [Mutation Observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) ...

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps using something like `getElementsByClassName` which returns a live collection of DOM elements with your class `my-element`. Then you can watch for changes in the collection and run your function when necessary.