# Center align my large photos, without a negative margin

Tags: html, css, tumblr

I created a tumblr theme, where everything is centered and 660px wide.

However, I also post large imagery that is 940px wide, and have been centering that by giving it a negative margin of -140px (940-660/2), but this is not ideal because I then have to post all images as this dimension, or they are just aligned way left.

Scroll to the bottom of my site to see the images that are not aligned properly: http://seans.ws

The css:

```
        section {display: block; clear: both; margin: 0 auto;width: 660px;}

        article img {clear: both; max-width: 940px; margin-left: -140px;}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Look into using javascript to dynamically position elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose between these two solutions:

Markup:

```
<div id="content">
  <div class="a"><div class="b">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100">
  </div></div>
  <div class="a"><div class="b">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/2000/100">
  </div></div>
```

Common css:

```
#content {
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
.a {
    /* extend image area */
    margin-left :-9999px;
    margin-right:-9999px;
    /* but without scrollbars */
    position: relative;
    left: -9999px;
}
.a .b {
    /* undo scrollbar-removing positioning */
    position: relative;
    left: 9999px;
}
```

The `display: table` way:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZhEku/3/

```
.a .b {
    display: table;  /* shrink-wrap to content (= the image) */
    width:   300px;  /* content width, acts as min-width when display:table */
    margin:  0 auto; /* center inside the (2*9999+300)px area */
}
```

The `display: inline-block` way:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZhEku/4/

```
.a {
    /* center content (= the image wrapped into .b) */
    text-align: center;
}
.a .b {
    display:    inline-block; /* shrink-wrap to content (= the image) */
    min-width:  300px;        /* content width */
    text-align: left;         /* if image is smaller than the content */
}
```

​Enjoy :)

Comment: Okay, it isn't really perfect because it adds a looong horizontal scrollbar to the page.

Comment: Yeah, and it then does not align the images that are smaller than the width specified in #content (like an image that is 200px won't left align flush with the red line I have at the beginning of each post /graphic designer geek ;)

Thank you though Biziclop!

Comment: How much "unnecessary" markup are you ready to tolerate for this effect? :)

Comment: haha, bring it on!

I could also just take care of the smaller images by just targeting images that are 940px wide with my negative margin in JavaScript right? I can always just always post imagery that is always 940px wide going forward :)

Comment: Hi, I updated my answer. You have to wrap each independent image into two divs.

Comment: Whoa :) Thanks...this place is so awesome.

Comment: Wooo! Thanks Biziclop. This works so much better than the jQuery I was trying. Check it out: http://seans.ws :)

Comment: Quick test: IE7: large images are aligned to red. IE8: some images are ok, some images with the same images are shifted too left + throws some JS errors.

Comment: My suggestions: **1** add `.a .b { max-width: 940px; }` to fix IE layout shifts **2** use the `inline-block` variant for ie7 support.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the infinite scroll js: http://static.tumblr.com/q0etgkr/ytzm5f1ke/infinitescrolling.js

Here is my margin-left script for images larger than the default width of containers:

```
    <!--Dynamicaly center big images-->
    <script>
    $(window).load(function() {
        $(function() {
            $('img').css('marginLeft', function(index, value){
                if($(this).width() > 660) {
                    return -($(this).width() - 660)/2;
                }
                return value;
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
```

The only thing I need to figure out is how to do this same function on images that dynamically load because I have infinite scroll (like the bottom images are not loaded until you go down the page.

Comment: If you fixed an image, add some class to it, like `.fixed-margin`. When a new bunch of image loads, just fix `img:not(.fixed-margin)`. Or you could listen to the `DOMNodeInserted` or some similar event: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143929/domnodeinserted-equivalent-in-ie