# DOMNodeInserted in the IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, cross-browser, dom-manipulation, mutation-events

Why doesn't this code work in IE? Please help fix it:

```
jQuery('body').live('DOMNodeInserted',function(e){
    var parent = jQuery(e.target).parent();
    parent.find("a").css('color','#AA62C6');
    parent.find('a').removeAttr('onmousedown');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This event is not supported in IE. This is added to IE9 but seems to be buggy in the implementation.

A solution will be to handle the dom manipulation at the base(The method which is changing the dom) level.

```
function update(){
    //do some dom manipulation
    $(window).trigger('customupdatedom', parent);
}
$(window).on('customupdatedom', function(e, parent){
    //handle dom change
})
```

You can also read the following
[DOMNodeInserted equivalent in IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143929/domnodeinserted-equivalent-in-ie)
[DOMNodeInserted event](http://help.dottoro.com/ljmcxjla.php)

Comment: Thank you for your help, but when I try to apply it to my trouble it still doesn't work.

Comment: I want to change 'a' css parameters before the page is loaded. There are two html link tags for css import..

Answer (score 0):

Use [onreadystatechange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536957) for IE:

```
var parent;

if (!!document.addEventListener)
  {
  jQuery('body').live('DOMNodeInserted',function(e){
    parent = jQuery(e.target).parent();
    parent.find("a").css('color','#AA62C6');
    parent.find('a').removeAttr('onmousedown');
    });
  }
else
  {
  jQuery("body").get(0).addBehavior("foo.htc");
  jQuery('body').get(0).attachEvent('onreadystatechange',function(e){
    parent = jQuery(e.target).parent();
    parent.find("a").css('color','#AA62C6');
    parent.find('a').removeAttr('onmousedown');
    });  
  }
```