# How to call a function in every element in the DOM even if they are dynamically created

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-on

I want to call a function over specific elements on my DOM, for example:

```
$(".red").css({backgroundColor: "pink"});
```

It works ok for any element already existing into the DOM, but I also want to this method to be called in elements dynamically added to the DOM.

I've tried things like:

```
$(".red").on(function(){ this.css({backgroundColor: "pink"}) });
```

or:

```
$(".red").on("load", function(){ this.css({backgroundColor: "pink"}) });
```

But not any success.

Check the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fguillen/22kwt/)

#### Update

The `.css()` call is just an example I actually want to call other kind of functions

Comment: Sorry, there's no easy or clean way of doing this cross-browser, assuming you're actually doing something other than `.css`.

Comment: Was cross-browser mentioned in the question?

Comment: Why don't you just add `background-color: pink;` to your CSS for the `.red` rule?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/22kwt/1/

Comment: No, there is not a generic way to call any function on all DOM elements, even those dynamically added. There are ways in code to set styles that apply to all elements. Please explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: After your update, this problem becomes really more complex.

Comment: @lan @j08691 Sorry for the misunderstanding.. the `.css()` call is just an example

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You were close.  Try:

```
$(document).on("load", ".red", function(){ this.css({backgroundColor: "pink"}) });
```

Oops, that doesn't work.  This does http://jsfiddle.net/4Bv9r/

```
$('body').on('DOMNodeInserted', ".red", function(){ $(this).css({backgroundColor: "pink"}) });
```

Comment: this doesn't work. http://jsfiddle.net/22kwt/2/ paragraph tags don't have a load event.

Comment: Just a note, `DOMNodeInserted` doesn't work on IE8 and below.

Comment: If you need to do IE, look at onreadystatechange and/or propertychange events.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143929/domnodeinserted-equivalent-in-ie & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15018590/domnodeinserted-in-the-ie

Comment: @fguillen And if you want to support newer browsers since `DOMNodeInserted` is deprecated, you can use a `MutationObserver`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver . You can detect support and fallback to older methods

Answer (score 1):

If you know the element is going to be added dynamically, the best way should be adding the rules to a stylesheet.

OR you can create style dynamically,

```
$("<style>").text(".red { background-color: pink; }").appendTo("head");
```

OR

Add this in your page `<style id='d_style'></style>` then

```
$('#d_style').text(".red { background-color: pink; }");
```

Comment: I think it'll be troublesome on IE

Comment: If what you're trying to do is as simple as changing the css, this is a much better solution.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding.. the `.css()` call is just an example