# adding an event to catch when a list item is added to a <select> jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using jQuery to add an event to a select (multiple) control. The idea is to execute this event when an item is added or removed from the list. I have tried the `$("#myselect").change()` function but this only throws the event when you select another item in the list. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:**

**HTML** *(auto generated for this example I put my id)*

```
<select id="myselect" style="width: 143px; height: 125px; overflow: scroll;" ondblclick="GipRemoveSelectedItems(ctl00_ctl19_g_f081466b_5035_4884_b6db_009508a22e1c_ctl00_ctl05_ctl01_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00_MultiLookupPicker_m); return false" onchange="GipSelectResultItems(ctl00_ctl19_g_f081466b_5035_4884_b6db_009508a22e1c_ctl00_ctl05_ctl01_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00_MultiLookupPicker_m);" multiple="multiple" jQuery172007786130460086404="3"/>
```

**jQuery** *- Inside of $(document).ready()*

```
$("#myselect").change(function() {
    //Does not enter on add or remove of an item
});
```

Comment: Please post a complete code example.

Comment: how do you add option to the select element?

Comment: Seems like you are looking for this: [custom events in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/399867/)

Comment: Just updated and before rating let me edit the question... I didnt post everything because of the simple fact that im not handling the html part i just need to know jquerys function to catch those events...

Comment: @A.Wolff Its a Sharepoint site so sharepoint does this for you. Pretty much the client asked to add functionality that isnt necesarily supported and to rework the whole form is to much for what the client wants so im trying to work around this with a hack... :(

Comment: @Mathletics The event executes but only when there are items in the list and you select another item not when adding or removing items...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can listen to the `DOMNodeInserted` event and check if the new element is an `option` into the specific `select`.

Check: [How to call a function in every element in the DOM even if they are dynamically created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18643898/how-to-call-a-function-in-every-element-in-the-dom-even-the-dynamically-created)

Comment: This worked perfect in firefox but not IE8 is there another way to do this that will work with ie8+??

Comment: I just found a work around using the add and remove option buttons that sharepoint creates so ill be using that method none the less the DOMNodeInserted would have been the solution with the limitation of browser compatibility thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 12):

You can use `DOMSubtreeModified` event and check if new element added to DOM. i.e, In your case new `option` to specific `select`.

```
$("#SELECT_ID").bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
    alert("tree changed");
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/eQErD/646/)**</kbd>

Comment: I don't see the event `DOMSubtreeModified` in the _quirksmode.org_ link :/

Answer (score 2):

Note the current answers have been deprecated in favour of the [`MutationObserver` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

The correct way is now like so:

```
$select = $('#myselect')
const observer = new MutationObserver(
    () => { $select.trigger('mutated') }
)
observer.observe($select[0], { childList: true })
```

Then to do something on the event trigger:

```
$select.on('mutated', () => { console.log('mutated') })
```