# Is there a reliable, cross-browser way to use polyfills with knockout?

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, internet-explorer-7, polyfills

We have a site that is driven pretty much entirely out of knockout and we need to support all major browsers, including Internet Explorer back to IE7 (not IE6).

Chrome already supports almost all of the HTML 5 features that we actually care about, and Modernizr handles the CSS hacks like a champ. But there are times when we still have to resort to polyfills, two notable examples being the `placeholder` attribute and more recently the `<details>` element.

Most of the polyfills are or rely on jQuery plugins, which is great in theory. Unfortunately, they also tend to be ineffective at dealing with dynamically loaded content - which there's a *ton* of when you use knockout (or any templating engine, really). Further complicating matters is that we're using knockout as true MVVM, so there's no decent place to shoehorn in a bunch of JS hacks to reload the plugins (which is probably a good thing as far as our architecture is concerned, but frustrating on this front).

We were able to come up with a semi-reliable implementation using the `DOMNodeInserted` event (deprecated, I know) for Firefox and IE9. Unfortunately it didn't work in IE8, because [legacy IE doesn't support it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2143929/38360) and it seems damn near impossible to replicate in those browsers. `onreadystatechange` seemed promising at first but the event tends to fire too early - even if `readyState` is explicitly checked - and the polyfills miss their targets, so to speak.

The only option we tried that actually worked reliably in IE7/IE8 was using a repeating timeout to rerun the polyfills every 50 ms. Unfortunately, that also consumed an entire CPU constantly, and bumping it up to even 100 ms caused a too-noticeable delay in the UI, so not really suitable for production use.

So: **Is there any reliable way of combining traditional polyfill techniques with dynamic content and templating engines like knockoutjs, that works in every major browser down to at least IE7?**

*(FWIW, we did eventually manage a workaround using knockout's `afterRender` binding, but that kind of takes the "poly" out of "polyfill". I'm hoping for something that we can write once and then forget about.)*

Comment: There probably isn't a cross–browser implementation of the placeholder attribute using feature detection. You may be tempted to use conditional comments for IE and ignore other browsers that don't support it. The simplest solution is not to depend on placeholders (you shouldn't be relying on them anyway) so if it's missing, users aren't bothered. Placeholders should not replace on–screen features such as labels or format hints since it disappears once content is entered, so any "help" value from the label or format hint is lost unless the content is removed.

Comment: @RobG: I'm afraid I'm not seeing the relevance of your comment beyond the very first sentence. Of course we don't depend on placeholders - by definition they are not really attributes that can be tied to any behaviour other than, well, placeholders. That doesn't mean it's OK for functionality to be crippled in the one browser that's used by the majority of our users. I don't think your proposed solution really solves the problem, nor will it work as any kind of moral justification to the business for not properly supporting the same features in all browsers.

Comment: And addressing the comment about conditional comments specifically - I'm sorry if I didn't make it clear in the question, but our challenge has absolutely nothing to do with causing the execution of code in IE only; that's been a solved problem for years. The difficulty lies in causing the execution of code *on markup or elements that are added long after the initial page load* - and doing *that* in IE as part of a knockout/MVVM framework.

Comment: I'm aware of your question and that I have no answer, hence I posted a comment. I'm sure you're aware of the following, but I'll post it anyway. It can be difficult for users to distinguish between a placeholder and a value, and since the behaviour of the two is entirely different, they can be confused and annoyed by them. Hence not having them in browsers that don't support them is a reasonable strategy that is certainly not crippling and might even be seen as a benefit.

Comment: @RobG: [The comments section is not meant as a general discussion forum](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment), it's meant for requesting and providing clarifications on the questions and answers. I hardly think that this is the appropriate medium to be discussing the usability of the `placeholder` attribute, especially since I (intentionally) made no reference to *how* we're using it, and we already have a [ux.se] site for that anyway. I appreciate you taking an interest in the subject but I'd prefer not to have the noise and don't believe this benefits other members either.

Answer (score 2):

The way I solved the same problem was to wrap most of my jQuery plugins, and behaviors in general, in knockout bindings (http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html). So I had, for example, a placeholder "binding" that I used on each input like `<input data-bind="placeholder:'Some Placeholder Text'"/>` that either simply set the `placeholder` attribute or did some IE hack depending on the need.

A broader solution would be to augment knockouts binding provider (http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/09/ko-13-preview-part-2-custom-binding.html). The binding provider is the thing that traverses the DOM (both on load and when dynamically loaded) and identifies bindings. By default, that essentially means it's just looking for data-bind attributes and ko comments, but you can change this to also find attributes like placeholder, input types for date or number inputs, etc, and add your IE hacks.

Comment: Not too keen on adding hacks everywhere, but the second option looks fairly promising.

Comment: @Aaronaught custom bindings are not hacks. They are an encouraged, normal way of adding behavior. The first option is the right way to go.

Comment: @Tyrsius: For when you want specific behaviour, yes; for polyfills (global behaviour), not so much.

Comment: @Aaronaught I am not sure I follow you. The examples you gave, `placeholder` and the `details` element, are perfect candidates for custom bindings. What behavior do you not think belongs in a binding handler?

Comment: @Tyrsius: A binding is what the first paragraph suggests - adding something like `data-bind="placeholder: 'Blah'"` all over the place. That's a hack. You may not think of it as a hack in terms of augmenting knockout's behaviour in a specific scenario, but it's a hack from the context of spot-fixing every issue instead of using one simple polyfill. The second option - changing the KO binding *provider* - *is* more of a hack to KO itself, but as an overall solution is much less of a hack, since it would work like any other polyfill.

Comment: @Aaronaught I understand, and that does make sense. I disagree that changing the binding provider is a hack, its an extension point they intentionally added in 2.0. Their is even documentation on how to do it.