# onChange of the count of objects event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been trying to find a way to detect every time the count of a particular object has changed in the DOM.

For example, assume class '.special' currently returns 5 objects:

```
$('.special').css('color','1px solid red');
```

Later on in time, the user results in the number of `.special` objects to increase or decrease.  So, as soon as the number of `.special` objects changes from 5, I would like an event to trigger.

Is this possible?

I tried using the `change` event for this, but it will not work in this instance.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: How a user can decrease or increase ? Put the event when the user is trying to increase or decrease this element

Comment: How are you adding additional elements? `click` event?

Comment: @MIIB Right, but what if there are 20 different ways a user can decrease or increase the count of elements in the DOM? I was trying to find an easier way to do this, to avoid duplicate code.

Comment: Can you provide html?

Comment: @Dom, yes binding a `click` event to a variety of different elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can capture the DOMNodeInserted event.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', function(e){
    alert($('.special').length);
});
```

[The problem is, this event is not supported by IE8 and before.](http://help.dottoro.com/ljmcxjla.php)

[Maybe you can find a workaround but I haven't tried](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143929/domnodeinserted-equivalent-in-ie).

[Here's a JSFiddle that works](http://jsfiddle.net/zAZ6z/).

Answer (score 0):

With your situation (there are 20 different ways a user can decrease or increase the count of elements in the DOM) one thing only comes to my mind. You should store your current `special` elements and could use a `setInterval` and try to call a function for example every 2 seconds  and check the `specials` count and compare it to the previous number. If they are not equal, then there's a change. And i would not suggest this method and i think it's better to put a `click` binding on all your different ways.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to solve this issue is to make a proxy method that creates ".special" objects. You need the event of creation to control the current number of elements in DOM, so, for example:

```
function createNewSpecial() {
    var specialCnt = $('.special').length;
    if (specialCnt > 5) {
        // magic
    }

    // creation of another ".special" element in DOM if needed
}
```

Comment: He mentioned that there are 20 different ways to increase or decrease the special objects. That's the problem

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to define a function that performs the operation you wish to happen on addition of a column, in example:

```
function on_add_column() {
  // do stuff
}
```

Now bind this function to all events that are causing the addition of a column, like `click`s, `ajax`s or what have you.

```
$("button#add").on("click", on_add_column)
$("a#add-link").on("click", on_add_column)
$("input#beh").on("change", on_add_column)
```

Using a timeout would mean having jQuery query the DOM on a set interval... which is not efficient. Also, you *should* know all of the actions that will cause the addition of a column within *your own* application.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this does involve some code but custom events might work.  Here I have a custom "specialEvent" that I fire, and a "trackChanges" function to do what you will.

I created a "tracker" function in a fiddle that simply adds a class depending on what changed here: http://jsfiddle.net/DsSQd/1/  and keeps track of the length previously seen in a "tracker" element - in this case the parent of the group.  It is a bit ugly, but you can do what you want there, in mine, I track the length of the group in the parent wrapper and simply add a class depending on whether the length changed or not, and if not, just highlight the element that fires the event.

```
// custom event handler
$(document).on('specialEvent', '.special, .changerthing, .friendly>.specialalso', function () {
    trackChanges(this, $(this).parent(), $(this).parent());//react to the change
});
// event where I trigger the handler
$('#wrapperToBindTo').on('click wacked', '.changers,.special,.changerthing', function () {
    $(this).trigger('specialEvent');
});
// event where I trigger the handler
$('.friendly').on('click', '.specialalso', function () {
    var me = $(this);
    me.clone().appendTo($(this).parent()).text(me.text() + ' Copy of:' + me.index()); //add one
    me.parent().find('.specialalso:last').trigger('specialEvent'); //fire special event
});
```

For example, we could then add this function:

```
//added to show a remove, then trigger that cascades
$('#wackFriendly').click(function(){
    $('.friendly>.specialalso').last().remove();
    $('.friendly>.specialalso').last().trigger('wacked');
});
```

and then handle that as seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/DsSQd/2/